# Swift: Is there a way to test if object cast as AnyObject conforms to Equatable?

Tags: ios, generics, swift2, equatable

I have an object that has keyed properties:

```
func value(key: String) -> AnyObject?
func setValue(value: AnyObject?, key: String)
```

I wish to check if the value returned from the `value` function with the same key from two different objects are `Equatable`. Swift complains because `Equatable` has a `Self` reference and can only be used in generics. Is there a way I can check to see if the `AnyObject` object returned from the `value` function conforms to `Equatable`?

Comment: I'm surprised how annoying it is to get this working even in 2020

Answer (score -5, accepted):

*Due to changes in Swift 2, I'm editing m'y answer*

To check protocol conformance, simply use `is` keyword.

But you can't do it when the protocol is using `Self` (note the capital S).

So you could do:

```
if let myValue = myObject.value(myKey) as? Equatable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What you suggest is not working. The swift compiler produces the following error: `Protocol 'Equatable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`